# Workarounds for testing cross browser functionality using Cypress?

Tags: testing, automation, cross-browser, cypress

I understand that at the moment Cypress.io does not have any cross browser testing capabilities. Despite that, I love the functionality and ease that it accomplishes most tests. However, I was just curious of anyone implementing a cross browser testing plan with an original automation strategy in Cypress!

Basically how do you cover the lack of cross browser testing until Cypress releases this functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, nobody has put together any separate libraries to cover this.

However, it is in Cypress.io roadmap and seems to be their main focus currently along with adding Saucelabs support.

See here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/310

Currently, it seems like just a bit of a waiting game, I expect a big release of this feature in 2019.

Comment: Do you personally use Cypress? I am pretty set on working with it but was wondering other peoples opinions on how I should cover the lack of cross browser testing for the time being! Thanks!

Comment: I personally do use Cypress, however the UI that we're currently testing doesn't have much need for cross-browser functionality so it appeals to me, we are finding issues across the way but its a combination of Cypress and the UI, remember Cypress is new as Selenium use to be! Some people need to give it a chance, what is the UI your testing built in?